# generate lwa Refresh Token not working in seller central dashboard

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws, amazon-selling-partner-api, amazonsellercentral

Hi I have a problem I am trying to use amazon sp-api for myself I registered an app on seller central dashboard but when I try to self authorize the app nothing happens in fact when I click on "authorize" button the circular indicator appears for a second but no refresh token is generated can anyone help me?